# data.result.response.airport.pluginData.schedule.arrivals.data[i].flight.airport[i] is undefined

Tags: angularjs, json

hi again am build app for schedule airport information for data flight airport arr and dep  , i have many arrays and am confused to use i try to use this way to coding but not working .

json array

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Qq0F.png)

error : http://www.3rbz.com/uploads/49fe2aa262501.png

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('starter.bgw', ['ionic']);

  app.controller('myctlr', function($scope, $http) {
    var service_url = "/airport.json?code=bgw";
    $http.get(service_url)
      .success(
        function(data) {
          $scope.city= data.result.response.airport.pluginData.details.name;
            console.log(data);
            bord = [];

            for(i=0; i<36; i++) {                 
              var arr  = data.result.response.airport.pluginData.schedule.arrivals.data[i].flight.airport[i].origin[i].name;
              bord.push({ arr: arr });
            }                   
        })
    })
  })();
```

json

```
{
  "result": {
    "response": {
      "airport": {
        "pluginData": {
          "schedule": {
            "arrivals": {
              "page": {
                "current": 1,
                "total": 2
              },
              "data": [
                {
                  "flight": {
                    "airport": {
                      "origin": {
                        "name": "Bahrain International Airport"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

get error Error: `data.result.response.airport.pluginData.schedule.arrivals.data[i].flight.airport[i] is undefined`

Comment: replace `.flight.airport[i].origin[i].name;` with `.flight.airport.origin.name;`

Comment: its same now working `Error: data.result.response.airport.pluginData.schedule.arrivals.data.flight is undefined`

Answer (score 0):

`airport[i]` isn't an array (also `origin`) but an object in your json example:

```
{
   "flight": {
     "airport": {
       "origin": {
         "name": "Bahrain International Airport"
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Then you can get `name` value with this line:

```
data.result.response.airport.pluginData.schedule.arrivals.data[i].flight.airport.origin.name;
```

`data` obviously has to have 36 elements for this loop: `for(var i=0; i<36; i++)`

Comment: can you log the `i`and `data[i]` in each loop?

Comment: `Error: i is not defined`

Comment: but when i make obviously 36 elements loop i put 1 i have no error

Comment: Ok. sorry i don't see that. Replace `for(i=0; i<36; i++)` with `for(var i=0; i<36; i++)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
As per your `json`, only `data` is `array` (I assume you have atleast 36 objects in `data` `array`)

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('starter.bgw', ['ionic']);

  app.controller('myctlr', function($scope, $http) {
    var service_url = "/airport.json?code=bgw";
    $http.get(service_url)
      .success(
        function(data) {
          $scope.city= data.result.response.airport.pluginData.details.name;
            console.log(data);
            bord = [];

            for(var i=0; i<36; i++) {                 
              var arr  = data.result.response.airport.pluginData.schedule.arrivals.data[i].flight.airport.origin.name;
                  bord.push({ arr: arr });
console.log(arr);
                }                   
            })
        })
  })();
```

Comment: hi , thank for you reply , you fixed 50% , but i still hava error `Error: data.result.response.airport.pluginData.schedule.arrivals.data[i] is undefined` see pic http://www.3rbz.com/uploads/96dd085f2c4e1.png

Comment: i use like this in html : `<div class="row" ng-repeat="day in bord">
   <h3>{{day.flights}}<h3> 

 
      </ion-content></ion-pane> `

Comment: Are you getting result from service? check your result form `$http` service and try to log in console for each object, if result is coming then, your object structure may be  different from as provided in screenshot in question.